# Can existing C-VISIT Visa be used for Business from April 2015 onwards?

Tags: visas, uk

I hold a UK 10-year C-VISIT Visa that was issued to me IN 2013 for Tourism. In view of the changes to the Visitor Category from April 2015, would I be able to use the existing Tourist Visa for Business Purposes? Greatly appreciate your views.

Answer (score 3):

On 24 April 2015 all type C UK visitor visas will automatically convert to the new `Visitor (standard)` category.

From that date forward, a business visitor will be permitted to engage in tourist activities, and a general visitor will be able to engage in business activities (as long as they are within the scope identified in [Part 2 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-rules-part-2).

Those currently holding one of the earlier general or business visas will be automatically converted and there is no need to do anything formal to make the conversion happen.

The controlling reference for this answer is the most recent [Statement of Changes](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/407476/HC_1025_Immigration_Rules.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the immensely useful answer. Is the information that you provided available in any official document such as the documents referred above? If so, could you provide the page number in the document so I may print the same for reference? Thanking You.

Comment: @user28490, the Home Office site will be amended with any other information you need by 24 April.  In the meantime, you can use the Statement of Changes in the link provided.

Comment: @GayotFow: Hi Gayot, I recently applied for UK visa. The type as mentioned in my visa application is `VISIT-BUSINESS-6 MONTHS`. But I got the visa granted with Type as `C-VISIT`. Based on your answer, I am assuming I should be able to engage both in tourist and business activities. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct